# how can you take out extra space in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to give a welcome message to recruiters that view my html webpage.  The javascript code I'm using is:

```
  function myFunction() {
                var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "");

                if (person == null) {
                    var message = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  
                    "Hello! Thank you for viewing my resume.";
                    message.innerHTML.replace((/\s/g,''));
                    
                }
                else  {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
                    "Hello " + person + "! Thank you for viewing my resume.";
                }
            }
```

The output in the html looks like Hello ! Thanks for viewing my resume.  I've tried flipping the else and if outputs but it still adds the extra space.  How can I fix this?  I know there are similar questions on stack but the solutions haven't worked in my case.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like the code is passing the conditional check however person is undefined or ''... Have you console logged person in your else section to see what it returns? ~ The extra space would then be the white space created when person is concatenated to your string.

Comment: Smart idea; using `prompt` to scare away recruiters. Brilliant! ;-) `message.innerHTML.replace((/\s/g,''));` does nothing. A [mcve] with HTML and a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) is a good idea.

Comment: `message.innerHTML = message.innerHTML.replace(/\s/g,'');`

Comment: I hope it won't scare away recruiters.  I'm a new developer just out of college and I want to show them I can do the basics.

Answer (score 0):

in this case I think you can use Template literals (Template strings), one feature of ES6.

```
function myFunction() {
                    const person = prompt("Please enter your name", "");

                if (!person) {
                    const message = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  
                    "Hello! Thank you for viewing my resume.";
                    message.innerHTML.replace((/\s/g,''));
                    
                }
                else  {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
                    `Hello ${person}! Thank you for viewing my resume.`;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The input would be labeled as Undefined which does not necessarily equal Null in JavaScript. My advice would be try creating a different way to check the name. Perhaps just give them the option "Continue as Guest" instead of checking for an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

> `message.innerHTML.replace((/\s/g,''));`

That line is doing absolutely nothing, `replace()` returns a new string, it doesn't modify the old one

And even if it replaced the old one, the desired output wouldn't really be what you're looking for, it would remove all spaces in the string, all of them.

The way you remove extra spaces is by using `.trim()`, `trim()` removes any extra spaces at the start and/or at the end of the string, so you would do: `message.innerHTML = message.innerHTML.trim();`

> `if (person == null) {`

This wouldn't work, since `prompt` would return an empty string if the user didn't provide anything and your explicitly checking if it is equal to `null` instead, the most "optimal" way for checking for that, is as [@Anh Tuan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11657021/anh-tuan) did, `if (!person)`, this works because empty strings, `undefined`, or `null` all are falsy, so this is a nice way to check for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
if (!person)
```

instead of:

```
if (person == null)
```

and it should work fine. Everything else can stay the same.